# DateTimePicker syntax

Tags: vb.net, validation, syntax, datetimepicker

```
    If DateTimePicker1.Value.Date = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date Then

        MessageBox.Show("Please enter appropriate Starting Date.", _
                        "User Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        DateTimePicker1.Focus()
        Return
    End If
```

I just want to make a validation about my `dateStart` DTP. I want to validate if I input the date yesterday, the `messagebox` will pop. My syntax is wrong. Please help me. I don't know what is the code for the date today. Because my Syntax is `DateTimePicker1` is equals to itself. I want `DateTimePicker1` `=` to date today. Thank you!

Comment: You want to validate the `DtPicker`? For example you cannot input like date yesterday? Is that what you want?

Comment: In the Properties of `DateTimePicker` it has a `MinDate` which means you can set what to be display to your `DateTimePicker`. If you set the `MinDate` today, and run your system, your system will be automatically validate the `DateTimePicker`, It will accept only the Present and Future date.

Comment: Setting MinDate property is much cleaner / better. No code needed just properties. It should also give you validation wherein you will not need any messagebox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Properties of `DateTimePicker` it has a `MinDate` which means you can set what to be display to your `DateTimePicker`. If you set the `MinDate` today, and run your system, your system will be automatically validate the `DateTimePicker`, It will accept only the Present and Future date. But this solution will not have a Pop-up Message like your code above.

But if you want a pop-up message, Try this code.

```
 If DateTimePicker1.Value < Date.Today Then
        MessageBox.Show("Date cannot be before today.")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'Insert else here
    End If
```

You cannot compare `DateTimePicker1` to itself because it will get it's own value and compare to itself. But you can use `Date.Today` and compare to your `DateTimePicker1`.

Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: Setting the `MinDate` property is definitely the way to go. Prevention is pretty much always better than cure, i.e. prevent the user selecting an invalid value rather than telling them to fix it if they do. To be clear, you would ned to set the property in code, probably in the `Load` event handler, because the actual value will vary from run to run.

Comment: Yes it will, and i recommend to use the `MinDate` property, But my second solution is just for suggestion only. But anyway Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello and welcome to SO**

If you want to be sure that in the `DateTimePicker` cannot exsist a date before today, just add this little sub on your form:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DateTimePicker1.MinDate = Date.Today
End Sub
```